# Kendo HTML.TextAreaFor will not update the data base it is bound to

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Here is the question:  When using a TextAreaFor, the data does not update the database when the event is triggered to update so that it looks like it has changed until the page is refreshed or moved away from then returned to.

Here is the code on the view.

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-body">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <label for="Id">Id</label>
        <br />
        <br /> @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Id)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="questionText">Question Text</label>
        <br /> @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.QuestionText, new { cols = 28, rows = 4, @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <label for="answerId">Correct Answer Id</label>
        <br /> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnswerId, new { @class="form-control", style="width:70px;"})
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 ">
        <label for="answerExplanation">Answer Explanation</label>
        <br /> @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerExplanation, new { @class = "form-control", cols = 75, rows = 4 })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-body panel-info">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button id="btnApprove" class="btn btn-danger">Update/Approve</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-success">Cancel Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 right">
            @Html.CheckBox("ckApprove") Approve on move
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button id="btnPrev" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Previous Question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>
            <button id="btnNext" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Next Question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
        </div>
```

Here is the script being used to update on move or button push

```
<script>
    var questionId = @Model.Id;
    var nextQuestionId = parseInt(@Model.NextQuestionId);
    var prevQuestionId = parseInt(@Model.PrevQuestionId);
    var autoApprove = true;

    function getQuestionId() {
        return {
            questionId: questionId
        };
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        autoApprove = ("@ViewBag.AutoApprove".toLowerCase() === "true");
        nextQuestionId = parseInt(@Model.NextQuestionId);
        prevQuestionId = parseInt(@Model.PrevQuestionId);
        console.log(@Model.NextQuestionId + "/" + prevQuestionId);

        if (nextQuestionId != 0) {
            $("#btnNext").removeClass("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#btnNext").addClass("disabled");
        }
        if (prevQuestionId != 0) {
            $("#btnPrev").removeClass("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#btnPrev").addClass("disabled");
        }

        $("#ckApprove").prop('checked', autoApprove);

        $("#answerGrid").removeClass("k-widget");

        $("#btnApprove").click(function() {
            updateQuestion();
        });

        $("#btnCancel").click(function() {
            window.location = "/backendQA"
        });

        $("#btnPrev").click(function() {
            // if checkbox is checked then updateQuestion()
            if ($("#ckApprove").is(':checked')) {
                updateQuestion();
                autoApprove = true;
            } else {
                autoApprove = false;
            }
            window.location = "/BackendQA/Questions?testId=" + @ViewBag.TestId + "&questionId=" + @Model.PrevQuestionId + "&autoApprove=" + autoApprove;
        });


        $("#btnNext").click(function() {
            // if checkbox is checked then updateQuestion()
            if ($("#ckApprove").is(':checked')) {
                updateQuestion();
                autoApprove = true;
            } else {
                autoApprove = false;
            }
            window.location = "/BackendQA/Questions?testId=" + @ViewBag.TestId + "&questionId=" + @Model.NextQuestionId + "&autoApprove=" + autoApprove;
        });

    });

    function updateQuestion() {
        // set autoApprove = is the checkbox checked?
        var test = @ (Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

        test.Id = $("#Id").val();
        test.questionText = $("#QuestionText").val();
        test.answerId = $("#AnswerId").val();
        test.answerText = $("#AnswerExplanation").val();

        console.log(JSON.stringify(test));

        $.ajax({
            url: "/BackendQA/Question_Update",
            data: JSON.stringify(test),
            method: "POST",
            contentType: 'test/json',
            complete: function(x, status) {
                var result = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
            },
            error: function(jq, status, e) {
                $("#message").html("<p style=\"color: red;\">An error occurred. Please contact support with the following information:</p>" + jq.status + "<br />" + jq.responseText + "<br />" + e);
            }
        })
    }
```

and here is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult Question_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, QaQuestionModel test)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            QaQuestions tests = new QaQuestions(test.Id);
            return Json(tests.Update(test), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
```

There is also a grid with inline editing that will not update also.

Comment: You send a POST, but the action seems to be serve a GET. Maybe it does not even called. Apply the [HttpPost] attribute on in the action method.

Comment: The console log shows the null inputs from ModelState.Clear and the new information, it just doesn't move to the SQL server.

Comment: Just a guess - try doing `tests.Update(test)` before your return.  Also, I'm assuming your data persistence is in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You send a POST, but the action seems to be serve a GET. Maybe it does not even called. Apply the [HttpPost] attribute on in the action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Question_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest      request, QaQuestionModel test)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        QaQuestions tests = new QaQuestions(test.Id);
        return Json(tests.Update(test));
    }
    return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
}
```

Comment: Ok, added the [HttpPost] per suggestion.  There was no change in the output.  It will show in the console log that the information has been changed, it does not show up changed in the SQL server and a refresh goes back to the original text.  Please explain why the [HttpPost] may have been necessary?  I have another page with the same syntax, going to a different Model, that is working fine.  Thank you for this suggestion.